# Send email according to input select value

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I need to make changes to an existing form by adding a dropdown menu where I will have two inputs and their values. The purpose is to send the form to **recipient_one** if **Address 1** is selected or to **recipient_two** when **Address 2** is selected. Address 1 needs to be the default value when nothing is selected.

Here is just the added HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="./index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset class="elist">  

        <legend>Select shop:</legend>

                 <select name="shop">

                            <option name="address-chosen" value="Tammsaare" >Tammsaare</option>
                            <option name="address-chosen" value="Ülemiste"  >Ülemiste</option>

                 </select>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

and the PHP:

```
    $action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : null;

$page = null;
$pages = array('info', 'en');
if( isset($_GET['page']) && in_array($_GET['page'], $pages) ) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}

if( !in_array($page, $pages) ) {
    $page = '';
}

$mail_sent = false;
if( $action == 'add' ) {

    //Test if it is a shared client
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    //Is it a proxy address
    }elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

        $message = '';
        $message .= 'Name: '.safe($_POST['name'])."\r\n";
        $message .= 'E-mail: '.safe($_POST['email'])."\r\n";
        $message .= 'Phone: '.safe($_POST['telephone'])."\r\n";
        $message .= 'Mark: '.safe($_POST['mark'])."\r\n";
        $message .= 'Model: '.safe($_POST['model'])."\r\n";
        $message .= 'Shop: '.safe($_POST['address-chosen'])."\r\n";
        $message .= "Wants newsletter: ".$soovib_uudiskirja = isset($_POST['newsletter']) ? "Yes" : "No";
        $message .= "\r\n";
        $message .= "\r\n";
        $message .= "\r\n";
        $message .= 'Aeg: '.date('d.m.Y H:i')."\r\n";
        $message .= 'IP: '.$ip."\r\n";

    $mail_data = array(
        'to_email' => 'email@mail.com',
        'from_email' => 'email@mail.com',
        'from_name' => 'Stock Cars',
        'subject' => 'Reservation',
        'message' => $message,

    );
    mail_send($mail_data);


    $mail_sent = true;
}


function safe( $name ) {
   return( str_ireplace(array( "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:" ), "", $name ) );
}


function mail_send($arr)
{
    if (!isset($arr['to_email'], $arr['from_email'], $arr['subject'], $arr['message'])) {
        throw new HelperException('mail(); not all parameters provided.');
    }

    $to            = empty($arr['to_name']) ? $arr['to_email'] : '"' . mb_encode_mimeheader($arr['to_name']) . '" <' . $arr['to_email'] . '>';
    $from        = empty($arr['from_name']) ? $arr['from_email'] : '"' . mb_encode_mimeheader($arr['from_name']) . '" <' . $arr['from_email'] . '>';

    $headers    = array
    (
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit',
        'Date: ' . date('r', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']),
        'Message-ID: <' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) . '@' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '>',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
        'X-Mailer: PHP v' . phpversion(),
        'X-Originating-IP: ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'],
    );

    mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($arr['subject']) . '?=', $arr['message'], implode("\n", $headers));}

    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {}
```

So the question is how do I reconstruct the array?

Comment: You can change the current array to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the email variable based on the form value:

```
//default is email 1
$email='email@mail.com';
if(isset($_POST['shop']) && $_POST['shop']=='Ülemiste') {$email='email2@mail2.com';}
$mail_data = array(
        'to_email' => $email,
        'from_email' => $email,
        'from_name' => 'Stock cars',
        'subject' => 'Reservation',
        'message' => $message,

    );
```

edited as per your edit - not sure how the umlaut will effect things though

Comment: I'm not very good with PHP, and I don't know how do use your code without getting semantics issues. So now I've added all of the PHP code.

Comment: I updated my answer to correct a syntax error and add a check, you should just be able to replace your existing array with the above code bock